# How to convert UTF→CP1251 and finally to URL-encoded %CA%F3%EF%E8%F2%FC+%EA%E2%E0%F0%F2%E8%F0%F3

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a phrase in Russian "*Купить квартиру*". I need to convert it to

```
%CA%F3%EF%E8%F2%FC+%EA%E2%E0%F0%F2%E8%F0%F3
```

Encoding looks like ANSI

Notice, if I **Uri.EscapeDataString(**"*Купить квартиру*"**)**, I get

```
%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83
```

But these strings are not equal.

Is there some correct way to convert?

Comment: Where is your data coming from? Are you sure it's not already in CP1251?

Comment: Since you are looking for non-standard way to represent non-ASCII text in Uri you have to do it yourself... Convert string to bytes in encoding of your choice and than %-encode for Url. Consider adding language tag so one can suggest possible implementation in that language.

Comment: @RedX, it doesn't matter where my data come from. There are two points - **given string** and **required string**. So I'm looking for way to convert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Uri.EscapeDataString` follows the URL spec [RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), which says to use UTF-8 character encoding.

You'll need to write your own function in custom M, like this:

```
let
    To1251URL = (input as text) as text => let
        ToBytes = Binary.ToList(Text.ToBinary(input, 1251)),
        ToText = Text.Combine(List.Transform(ToBytes, (b) => "%" & Number.ToText(b, "X"))),
        FixSpace = Text.Replace(ToText, "%20", "+")
    in
        FixSpace,
    Applied = To1251URL("Купить квартиру")
in
    Applied
```